# Выполнение js при потере фокуса полем ввода

Tags: javascript, html

Возникла такая проблема. Есть поле ввода

```
<input type="number" onblur="func()" />
```

Когда данное поле теряет фокус, то выполняется функция js (func). В данном скрипте идет отправка данных на сервер, где данные заносятся в БД. Все работает как надо, но, если пользователь ввел данные в этот инпут и закрыл браузер или вкладку, то данные на сервер не уходят. Как быть? Как исправить это?

Comment: может добавить кнопку отправить?

Comment: у меня таблица этих инпутов 30*30. На сервере проще сделать по одному пришедшему инпуту добавление, а не сразу по всей куче.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('foo');

input.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
  console.log('Sending data to server...');
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="foo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать другое событие, например `oninput`, правда в этом случаи любое изменение значения будет отсылаться на сервер сразу же

```js
function func() {
  var num = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  console.log('sending changed value to server (value = ' + num.value + ')')
};
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="func()" />
```

Comment: и при каждом изменении будет происходить изменение в БД? то есть, например, если я буду вводить туда строку, ну допустим из 10 символов, то в базе эта запись будет обновляться 10 раз для каждого символа? По моему, это не есть хорошо.

Comment: @NoName можно еще попробовать поиграться событием `beforeunload`, чтобы при попытке закрытия браузер спрашивал уверен ли юзвер что хочет закрыть ибо данные могут потеряться и ращитывать уже на юзвера

Comment: Вот и я думаю так. Фокус у объекта ж будет потерян, если выскочит сообщение. Так что в любом случае данные уйдут